# Rest DSL with Springboot on Camel creates routes after restarting EAP throws Exception

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, jbossfuse, jboss-eap-6

When i tried to do a rest dsl with springboot project following the link here :

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/03/26/camel-spring-boot-rest-dsl/

The overall skeleton of my source code is like below :

```
        rest("http://localhost:8080/camel-services/rest/Test1")
        .post()
        .to("direct:route1");

         from("direct:route1")
        .to("mock:route");
```

The springboot version used is : **1.5.1.RELEASE** and i am trying to deploy the WAR file in **EAP-6.4.0** with **fuse-eap-installer-6.2.1.redhat-169.jar** installed on the EAP.

When i deploy the application for the first time it works but when i undeploy and restart the EAP and deploy it again it fails, it creates a id for the post request so the next time the application startup fails with the following exception :

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route post1 because of duplicate id detected: post1. Please correct ids to be unique among all your routes.
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1134) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3731) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3445) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:209) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3253) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3272) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3165) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133) [camel-spring-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
        ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not run Spring Boot inside another app server like EAP / JBoss WildFly.

The error you get smells like the undeploy procedure does not fully undeploy all resources. I know there was a recent bug in wildfly-camel that was fixed, but it was related to using camel-cxf and hot-deploying.

So my first advice would be to not use Spring Boot inside EAP and just use standard JEE on EAP. See the widlfly-camel docs and examples: https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel

Comment: Thanks claus with springboot embedded tomcat it works fine.. but due to it being a sub project and client requirement I am forced to use EAP... any sample projects /guidelines to follow to try it out on EAP and the best way to implement it out... I see post1 getting created in routes automatically so the next time I am starting it fails... any way to stop the post1 route getting created automatically ?

Comment: If you are going to run on EAP with Fuse installed then you'll want to disable the Camel subsystem because it'll likely interfere with your Spring Boot deployments.